# Display new entry at the top on combobox selection event with lines separating each new entries

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 1 combobox control in which I have lots of countries.

Now on this comboxbox selection I want to display something like this:

[image: Desired Output]

**Note**: Latest Selection should always comes first that is at the top.

Each time any country is selected I want to create entry in this control and this entry should come at the top.

I am working on `winform` for the first time so I don't have idea that what control should I use to achieve this same result.

I am not sure which control to use so right now I have used `textbox` control.

This is what I have done:

```
private void CountriesForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] Countries = Countries.GetallCountries();
            foreach (var item in Countries 
            {
                cmbCountries.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            cmbCountries.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

private void cmbCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(cmbCountries.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                if(txtCountries.Text.Count() > 0)
                {
                    txtCountries.Text.Text = "_____________________________________" + txtCountries.Text + cmbCountries.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtCountries.Text = cmbCountries.SelectedItem.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not what you are asking, I know (I will look into it now) but you can really simplify the filling of the combo with: `cmbCountries.DataSource=Countries.GetallCountries();`   

No need of saving the array and going all over it. And if the combo is displaying weird names (`System.[...]`) you just need to change the `toString()` method of the class Country

Comment: @Aimnox:Thanks for the suggestion.i will definitely change it but that is not a big issue.My main functionality is the desired output in the image which i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend to use a ListBox, you just need to pass it the items that you want to show, strings in that case. ListBox does not add a line between items but you can still diferenciate them.

So once you have add the listbox to the form, lets asume its called lbSelec. You just need to:

```
private void cmbCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String toAdd= "Country Selected :";
    toAdd+=cmbCountries.Text;
    toAdd+="      " //You can make it to more or less " " depending on the length of the country name
    toAdd+="DateTime: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

    lbSelect.items.Insert(0,toAdd);
}
```

Comment: My main concern is the line which will seperate each output.
I
I

Comment: Then you will need to change the drawing of the listbox. Never done it, but here is how. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051781/how-do-i-draw-a-line-between-listboxitems

Comment: Is there a way to draw line when adding new entries in listbox or whatever control ?

Comment: I have tried that solution but lines are not getting drawn in between records with list box

Comment: @Learning Have you modified `DrawMode` property of the listbox?

Comment: Sorry but i dont know know about this property.What value should i set  in it?

Comment: I'm no expert, so I may be wrong. All the controls have a DrwanMode property (accesible from th design view) It can be setted to normal (The default drawn) or OwnerDrawFixed (It will be a custom draw). See this for an example and how to implement it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113005/discussion-between-learning-and-aimnox).